# How are ArrayLists implemented in Java?

Tags: java

Did some searching before asking, some not-so-reliable sources suggest that there's an underlying `Object[]` array.

Is it as simple as that? i.e. it handles resizing when necessary, maybe does a few tricks like doubling the size to get better amortized runtimes, and keeps track of where the first empty slot in the array is.

Or, are there optimizations done for membership testing and sparse arrays?

Comment: It is as simple as that.

Comment: You know you can look at the source, right?

Comment: Sun's JDK includes src.zip.  You really could read the source code right there.

Comment: What a confusing name. Makes one wonder whether it is an array with an interface of a list or vice versa...

Comment: @gigadot He was asking about the implementation of `ArrayList`, not advice when using one. Additionally, `ArrayList` documentation enforces that the capacity of an `ArrayList` be managed such that `ArrayList::add` has amortized constant time. If `ArrayList::add` resized the underlying memory each time it was called, it would have `n^2` complexity. Something as simple as doubling capacity each time more space is needed guarantees amortized constant time. It'll do many fewer changes to capacity than increasing it by one each call to `ArrayList::add`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is an array of Object.  From the source:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

```
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the underlying Object[] is managed as you first surmised, including array growth by 50%.  No optimizations for membership testing; just straight searching through the list elements, one by one.

It's worthwhile to look at the source code linked by TofuBeer… you can learn a lot by studying the formality, optimization, and "defensive coding" of Sun's/Oracle's engineers.

Comment: One should just not forget that there may be one reason or the other why something is implemented in one particular way. Especially all classes that were retrofitted with generics may be implemented in a rather convoluted or "suboptimal" manner for backcomp reasons.

Comment: According to the linked source code, it grows by 50% each time it expands, not double.

Answer (score 3):

An `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` and implements four interfaces viz. `List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable`.

And it stores elements in an `Object[]` array as: `private transient Object[] elementData;`

If you say: `ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();` then by default it creates an `ArrayList` of size `10`.

There is a method `private void grow(int minCapacity)` which resizes the `ArrayList`